# Speeding up lists and for loops python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, cartesian-product

I have a question on how to speed up the following code, where I have two separate nested lists, which are compared to each other:

```
List1 = [['apple', 'banana'], ['kiwi', 'orange'], ['apple','kiwi'], ['blueberry', 'banana'],['coconut','grape']]
List2 = [['kiwi', 'orange', 'coconut'], ['banana','apple','blueberry', 'coconut'], ['banana','orange','grape'],['apple','kiwi'],['blueberry']]

def smoothies(List1, List2):

    if "banana" in List1 and "coconut" in List2:
        result = 'Smoothie1'

    elif "kiwi" in List1 and 'banana' in List2:
        result = 'Smoothie2'

    elif 'apple' in List1 and 'grape' in List2:
        result = 'Smoothie3'

    elif 'blueberry' in List1 and 'apple' in List2:
        result = 'Smoothie4'

    elif 'grape' in List1 and 'blueberry' in List2:
        result = 'Smoothie5'

    else:
        result = 'None'

    return result
```

The idea is that both lists are compared for all potential combinations and all options are appended to a new list. It would be great if someone could also explain the why so I can understand it better! Thank you!

Comment: What does the `smoothies` function have to do with that? And combine how? How should the result list look like?

Comment: To me it seems like your current code is equivalent of `def smoothies(List1, List2): return None` because you have nested lists. Are you sure you are showing the correct function here?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `[smoothies(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in product(List1, List2)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The idea is that both lists are compared for all potential
>   combinations and all options are appended to a new list.

For a variable number of variables, you can use a dictionary.

To calculate the pairwise Cartesian products of your two lists, you can use `itertools.product` with `map`. Then use a dictionary comprehension to map unique combinations:

```
from itertools import chain, product

products = set(chain.from_iterable(map(product, List1, List2)))

res = {smoothie: f'Smoothie{idx}' for idx, smoothie in enumerate(products, 1)}
```

Result:

```
{('apple', 'banana'): 'Smoothie7',
 ('apple', 'coconut'): 'Smoothie3',
 ('apple', 'grape'): 'Smoothie13',
 ('apple', 'kiwi'): 'Smoothie2',
 ('apple', 'orange'): 'Smoothie4',
 ('banana', 'apple'): 'Smoothie9',
 ('banana', 'coconut'): 'Smoothie8',
 ('banana', 'kiwi'): 'Smoothie11',
 ('banana', 'orange'): 'Smoothie17',
 ('blueberry', 'apple'): 'Smoothie16',
 ('blueberry', 'kiwi'): 'Smoothie15',
 ('coconut', 'blueberry'): 'Smoothie10',
 ('grape', 'blueberry'): 'Smoothie12',
 ('kiwi', 'apple'): 'Smoothie21',
 ('kiwi', 'banana'): 'Smoothie1',
 ('kiwi', 'blueberry'): 'Smoothie23',
 ('kiwi', 'coconut'): 'Smoothie22',
 ('kiwi', 'grape'): 'Smoothie20',
 ('kiwi', 'orange'): 'Smoothie19',
 ('orange', 'apple'): 'Smoothie6',
 ('orange', 'banana'): 'Smoothie18',
 ('orange', 'blueberry'): 'Smoothie14',
 ('orange', 'coconut'): 'Smoothie5'}
```

If, on the other hand, you are looking for all combinations *across sublists*, you can flatten your input lists and use `product` directly.

Comment: thank you for your comment - I'm not far advanced in python and have not come across this: f'Smoothie{idx}' - is this a way of referring to the index of a dictionary?

Comment: This is just a way to make a string in Python 3.6+, equivalent to `'Smoothie'+str(idx)` but, as you can see, cleaner (and more efficient).

Comment: @jpp I would say `f'Smoothie{idx}'` is equivalent to `'Smoothie{}'.format(idx)`. Saying it is equivalent to `'Smoothie'+str(idx)` is a bit misleading, because formatting is not based on string concatenation (which is oftentimes misused by Python newbies).

Comment: @EliKorvigo, Good point. I was trying to demonstrate the effect. Possibly `str.format` now needs explaining to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the smoothies for all the combinations of sub-lists of fruits:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [(l1, l2, smoothies(l1, l2)) for l1, l2 in product(List1, List2)]
[(['apple', 'banana'], ['kiwi', 'orange', 'coconut'], 'Smoothie1'),
 (['apple', 'banana'], ['banana', 'apple', 'blueberry', 'coconut'], 'Smoothie1'),
 ... many more ...
 (['coconut', 'grape'], ['apple', 'kiwi'], 'None'),
 (['coconut', 'grape'], ['blueberry'], 'Smoothie5')]
```